# R assign column to dataframe with variable name

Tags: r, syntax

Assign to a dataframe colum with a variable name.

```
getModified <- function(dframe, destination_string, foo, bar) {
    # complex calculations on foo and bar getting mynewcol here
    # ...

    # I want to add mynewcolumn with name in destination_string
    # if "blah" was the destination_string, the result would be as:
    #dframe$blah <- mynewcol
    #return(dframe)

    # what is the syntax for using the variable?
    # no luck here:
    dframe[, destination_string] <- mynewcolumn
    return(dframe)
  }
```

so that I could call

```
dframe <- getModified(dframe, "nameofmynewcolum", foo, bar)
dframe$nameofmynewcolumn
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue?  This seems to work for me.

Comment: well, would you look at that ... they both work ... I wonder what was going on.

Answer (score 7):

The syntax is

```
dframe[[destination_string]] <- mynewcolumn
```

For example,

```
getModified <- function(dframe, destination_string, foo) {
  dframe[[destination_string]] <- foo
  dframe
}
>     getModified(data.frame(A=1:10), "newColName", 11:20)
    A newColName
1   1         11
2   2         12
3   3         13
4   4         14
5   5         15
6   6         16
7   7         17
8   8         18
9   9         19
10 10         20
```

Comment: wow, awesome answer, but I was just missing something else. It appears that `dframe[, destination_string] <- mynewcolumn` works, as well.

Comment: Please review the R-FAQ: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-turn-a-string-into-a-variable_003f

Comment: This seems to work only if `dframe` is not empty (must have at least one column). Try `dframe <- data.frame(); df[["foo"]] <- 1:4`, you'll get an error "Error in '[[<-.data.frame'('*tmp*', "foo", value = 1:4) : 
  replacement has 4 rows, data has 0". Seen with R version 4.1.2. This can be a problem if you want to build up your data frame column by column in a loop. Yes, sometimes you need that, even though it's not the R way.